# MS Access SQL Syntax error "FROM" Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, syntax-error

I'm new to SQL and I am having a little trouble with my relational database. Below is my SQL, I am getting a "FROM" clause error when I try run the code but cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   ProgrammingLanguage,
   InventorSecondName,
   LanguageInventors,
   InventorSecondName  
FROM
   ProgrammingLanguage  
INNER JOIN
   LANGUAGE Inventors 
      ON Programming LANGUAGE.InventorsSecondName=LANGUAGE Inventors.InventorsSecondName
)  
ORDER BY
    Programming LANGUAGE.InventorSecondName
```

Comment: There is an unnecessary *close parenthesis* before `ORDER BY`

Comment: SQL queries only have one `FROM` clause.  You should also show sample data and the desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Didn't see that :D

Comment: Just spotted that :D. ill be honest, im very new to all of this, only studying it through distance learning so having a tough time with it. Two queries that represent a join and selection operation on the data. This is what i have to do with the data.

Comment: Just to add, i had initially tried this way but was getting a "Missing Operator" error in the first line of the query.                                   SELECT ProgrammingLanguage.InventorSecondName, LanguageInventors.InventorSecondName
FROM Programming Language
INNER JOIN Language Inventors 
ON
Programming Language.InventorSecondName=Language Inventors.InventorsSecondName

Comment: Suggestion: Use the Query Designer in Access to build your queries and look at the SQL generated by the tool. It's a great way to learn and also get useful results in a hurry.